# Determine number of objects in box by shaking

Tags: waves, acoustics

Given a container filled with identical objects, how could I find the number of objects in the container accurately purely by analyzing the sound produced on shaking? More specifically, which acoustic parameter should I focus on? Some ideas I have had so far are:

Looking at the number of amplitude "spikes" since the more objects there are, the more collisions there are

Using Fourier Transform to break down the combined sound into its constituent frequencies, finding the number of distinct frequencies. Unfortunately, I am not sure if the frequencies will be measured for each object, since the objects are identical

Comment: I don’t think that either of the two approaches will allow for good estimation. In the first case you’d have to take into account the distance of the objects to the box boundaries and their mean free path to extract some statistical metrics for the average distance/time between successive collisions and also account for the collisions between objects inside the box. The second approach could potentially be the same thing with the first but allow for analysis of the mean frequency of collisions in the frequency domain (direct comparison of results).

Comment: what approach, using the sound produced, would allow for a good estimation?

Comment: Perhaps by how loud the sound is? Each collision produces a click, and the clicks add to the total sound.

Comment: @temp124y the problem at hand is rather complex in nature. I can’t really think of a direct solution to it. I would most probably start with some measurements to compare the sound characteristics when only the number of items change in a box. This could possibly provide some indications as to what a “good” (in the sense of providing enough information and being robust) metric would be for the estimation.